# What does KDA stand for in Halo 5 and how is it determined?

Tags: terminology, halo-5-guardians

In Halo 5, there is a stat called KDA. I was figuring that it stood for Kill Death Average, but my stats are as follows:

[image]

Obviously 69 kills / 67 deaths do not equal 2.0.   What is KDA and how is the math calculated?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You're close.  KDA stands for "Kills, Deaths, *Assists*".

In most games it's simply `(kills+assists)/deaths`, but for Halo, it appears to be

`(K+(A/3)-D)/GamesPlayed`

In your case: `(69+(36/3)-67)/7==2`

Comment: Which would make that number the average surplus of kills (and assists counting for one third of a kill) you get compared to your deaths? 0 would then be equal to a (classic) KD of 1?

Comment: Are you sure its usually `(K+A)/D`? I dont have any references but I from what I remmeber assists usually get a divisor because you dont need to do as much to earn it.

Comment: @DavidGrinberg I'm just going off my experience.  There isn't really a hard and fast rule for how assists count.

Comment: @Flater I believe that is correct, yes.

Answer (score -1):

The classic efficacy scores for FPSs are actually ratios- not averages.

KD. Kills to Deaths. ie 5:5 got simplified to 1
Focus on single player, usually only rewards final blows

KAD (KA/D).  Kills plus Assists to Death.  8 plus 2 to 5 (10 to 5) simplified to 2
Accused of over rewarding assists, but the metric isn’t about individual scoring, this is still a great way to see how actively and well a player usually plays as a teammate (ie say you’re set up as a team in fixed fire positions the enemy keeps charging from and past the left gunner who’s spray of auto fire leaves targets for the mid gunner to single shot for the kill; LG gets 10 assists no kills, MG gets 10 kills no assists but both would have the same KAD in that scenario)

KDA (sometimes KDa or KD/A) Kills plus reduced/divided Assists to Deaths.  Focus back on individual efficiency with some crediting for teamwork.  4 kills plus (4 assists/2) to 6 deaths simplifies to 1.